# Atualizar uma viewbag (c# razor) com uma variável javascript

Tags: javascript, c#, razor

Talvez aquilo que eu queira fazer possa ser impossível, por questões do lado do servidor e do navegador, mas eu gostaria de fazer o seguinte:

```
<script>
    function pegarId(id) {
        $('@ViewBag.Id').value = $(this).attr("id");        
    }
</script>
```

Agradeço desde já, qualquer dica ou ajuda.

Comment: Não é possível fazer isso. Para comunicares entre navegador e servidor tens de usar pedidos http (ou submissao de formularios, ou entao pedidos AJAX).

Comment: Você quer selecionar o elemento em função do que está armazenado na  `ViewBag`, ou quer atribuir um valor à `ViewBag.Id`?

Comment: Você poderia dar mais detalhes do que você quer fazer? Ficou um pouco confuso o que vc está pedindo.

Comment: @Lucas tente [editar](http://pt.stackoverflow.com/posts/89790/edit) a sua pergunta e descrever um pouco melhor o seu propósito, que talvez possamos lhe ajudar com uma solução melhor para o seu problema.

Comment: Poderia nos informar qual o cenário que está tentando utilizar? Seria mais fácil para encontrarmos uma solução melhor para te ajudar.

Answer (score 1):

Não é possível alterar a ViewBag a partir do Javascript uma vez que a ViewBag é um recurso que funciona inteiramente no lado do servidor.

O contrário, no entanto, é possível: você pode definir uma variável javascript que receba um valor que será escrito a partir da ViewBag durante a renderização da View. Algo como:

```
<script>
    var umaVariavel = @ViewBag.MeuValor
</script>
```

Comment: muuuito obrigado!